# Is pointf rounded when compared with point?

Tags: c#, comparison, point

I need to compare a PointF to a Point as follows:

```
PointF myPointF = new PointF(1.1,1.1);
Point myPoint = new Point(1,1);
bool Equal = (myPointF == myPoint);
```

But I want to know which of the following are true or if something different is true of how the comparison really occurs:

1. myPoint is converted to a PointF first
2. myPointF is rounded to a Point first
3. something altogether different and unpredictable

One could write a test but I want to see the answer guaranteed in documentation.

Also, [there exists an implicit conversion from Point to PointF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.point.op_implicit%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) and not the reverse so I *think* that's enough to say the Point is being converted to a PointF but again, I don't know for sure.

Comment: Did you tried reverse engineering the code?

Comment: You are thinking correct, any conversion which happens implicitly will not involve any data loss so int is converted to float

Comment: Personally, I'd trust the result of an actual test over what the documentation says.

Comment: @Yossarian Do you mean by compiling to the intermediate language? I know an intermediate language exists but I'm not familiar with it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using LinqPad, it's easy to look at the IL to see what's going on. Basically, `Point` is converted to `PointF` and then the `==` equality method is called for `PointF`.

For example, using this code:

```
System.Drawing.PointF myPointF = new System.Drawing.PointF(1.1f ,1.1f);
System.Drawing.Point myPoint = new System.Drawing.Point(1,1);
bool equal = (myPointF == myPoint);
Console.WriteLine(equal);
```

Produces the following IL:

```
IL_0001:  ldloca.s    00 // myPointF
IL_0003:  ldc.r4      CD CC 8C 3F 
IL_0008:  ldc.r4      CD CC 8C 3F 
IL_000D:  call        System.Drawing.PointF..ctor
IL_0012:  nop         
IL_0013:  ldloca.s    01 // myPoint
IL_0015:  ldc.i4.1    
IL_0016:  ldc.i4.1    
IL_0017:  call        System.Drawing.Point..ctor
IL_001C:  nop         
IL_001D:  ldloc.0     // myPointF
IL_001E:  ldloc.1     // myPoint
IL_001F:  call        System.Drawing.Point.op_Implicit   //<- convert Point to PointF
IL_0024:  call        System.Drawing.PointF.op_Equality  //<- PointF equality
IL_0029:  stloc.2     // equal
IL_002A:  ldloc.2     // equal
IL_002B:  call        System.Console.WriteLine
```

If you use ILSpy, you can find the contents of both `Point.op_Implicit` and `PointF.op_Equality`.

```
// System.Drawing.Point
public static implicit operator PointF(Point p)
{
    return new PointF((float)p.X, (float)p.Y);
}

// System.Drawing.PointF
public static bool operator ==(PointF left, PointF right)
{
    return left.X == right.X && left.Y == right.Y;
}
```

This demonstrates that the `int` values are converted to `float` values when the `Point` is converted to a `PointF`, and then the `float` values from the original `PointF` instance and the converted `PointF` instance are compared.

Comment: Perfect. More in depth than I could have asked for.

Answer (score 3):

Let's see what ildasm.exe shows:

```
IL_001f:  call       valuetype [System.Drawing]System.Drawing.PointF [System.Drawing]System.Drawing.Point::op_Implicit(valuetype  [System.Drawing]System.Drawing.Point)
IL_0024:  call       bool [System.Drawing]System.Drawing.PointF::op_Equality(valuetype [System.Drawing]System.Drawing.PointF,valuetype [System.Drawing]System.Drawing.PointF)
```

So, yes. The Point gets treated as a PointF for the comparison.